# Array.ConvertAll() and ToArray() method, which is better?

Tags: c#, arrays, type-conversion, readline, jagged-arrays

Which of the following method is better to read from console and storing it into Int array? Is there any difference between the 2?

```
int[][] s = new int[3][];
            for(int i=0; i<elements.Length;i++)
            {
                s[i] = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
            }
```

OR

```
int[][] s = new int[3][];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            s[i] = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), sTemp => Convert.ToInt32(sTemp));
        }
```

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: If they give the same result, then both are good. If you have performance issue, you may profile it. Btw, I'd suggest using a one dimension array of a strcut `Foo[]` instead of jagged array `int[][]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly these aren't equivalent, in one version you are using `int.Parse(x)` in another `Convert.ToInt32(sTemp)`

That aside, you have found a perfect example of how to do something more than one way... In programming you will find this a lot.

`ConvertAll()`

> Converts an array of one type to an array of another type.

`Select()`

> Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.

`ToArray()`

> Creates an array from a IEnumerable.

Technically, in combination they produce the same thing, yet got about it in slightly different ways due to the fact they are part of slightly different areas of the *BCL* that have concerns in slightly different domains.

Personally i don't see `ConvertAll` used all that much these days as people are very familiar with *LINQ* and like to chain methods.

As to which is better for performance, we would have to write a lot of tests to figure this out, and it would come down to allocations verse speed per array size per platform. However, i feel the difference would be relatively indistinguishable in day to day, and my guess is you would be struggling to find very much performance difference at all at any significant sigma categorically.

In short, use what **You** like